# Overwriting multiple partitions bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

say I have a table `t1` which is date partitioned on column `sdate`

I have another table `t2` which is also partitioned on column `pdate` which has data already in some partitions (20200101 to 20200130)

Now, I want to overwrite few partitions ( 20200105 to  20200110) in `t2` from data in `t1`

and I want to do it in a single query and not one query per partition.

Select Query:

```
SELECT sdate,
c1, c2

FROM `dataset.t1` where sdate between "2020-01-05" and "2020-01-10"
```

I have seen examples where we can specify destination table like `t2$20200102`, but that will overwrite only a single partition.

How can we write insert statement to populate selected partitions

Any ideas of how the insert query would look like?

Comment: Is there any primary key which can correlate the rows in table t1 and table t2?

Comment: No, There isn't any key. My only purpose is to overwrite partitions in t1 with data from t2

Comment: I asked that because to use merge, updating and deleting rows you would need a primary key to relate these two tables. Otherwise, the answer from Guillem Xercavins is the best option.

Comment: Agree.
I was looking for something which is "atomic". Since there are multiple steps involved, we might end up in inconsistent state if any of the step fails

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `SELECT sdate AS pdate` in your `INSERT` statement:

```sql
INSERT dataset.t2 (pdate, c1, c2) 
  SELECT sdate AS pdate, c1, c2
  FROM dataset.t1
  WHERE sdate BETWEEN "2020-01-05" and "2020-01-10"
```

Of course, this will append the rows to each target partition so, if you want to overwrite them, you can delete them first with:

```sql
DELETE
  dataset.t2
WHERE
  pdate BETWEEN "2020-01-05" AND "2020-01-10"
```

Obviously, you should be careful when deleting partitions. An extra check can be added if you only want to overwrite dates with data in the source table:

```sql
DELETE
  dataset.t2
WHERE
  pdate IN (
    SELECT sdate 
    FROM dataset.t1 
    WHERE sdate BETWEEN "2020-01-05" AND "2020-01-10")
```

You can also consider using [`MERGE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#using_a_merge_statement) but then you would need to take into account what happens when matching row by row.

I did some tests with this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/7ba13e46f99c361dc330f7b8f5333def).

Another option is to do a piece-wise `SELECT` query to break the data into three date ranges and `UNION ALL` to bring them together.

```sql
SELECT * FROM dataset.t2
WHERE pdate < "2020-01-05" OR pdate > "2020-01-10"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dataset.t1
WHERE sdate BETWEEN "2020-01-05" AND "2020-01-10"
```

This requires specifying a destination table with `WRITE_TRUNCATE` and runs in a single job but has to essentially re-write the whole table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am looking for something which can be done in one step. But this helps too

Comment: Also, in this, the process is not atomic since multiple steps are involved.

Comment: Why use DML? it costs $$$. use the 'bq cp' cli or the API libraries and perform it with single command (per partition). This operation is atomic and loading/copying does not cost anything.
Docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#copying_multiple_partitions