# Query over multiple partitions bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

My bigquery table is partitioned by a column named: business_day

I'm trying to get all rows within certain business_days.
For example,

```
select *
from table
where
    business_day >= "2018-12-01" and business_day <= "2019-01-01"
    or business_day >= "2019-12-01" and business_day <= "2010-01-01"
    or business_day >= "2020-12-01" and business_day <= "2021-01-01"
```

I get this error:

> Cannot query over table 'table' without a filter over column(s) 'business_day' that can be used for partition elimination

Is there a way to do this without using [UNION ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247564/1059860)?

Here is the table info:

```
Table expiry: Never
Data location: EU
Table type: Partitioned
Partitioned by: Day
Partitioned on column: business_day
Partition filter: Required
```

What am I missing?

Comment: created table meeting above description with partition filter required and I cannot reproduce this problem! query scans only needed partitions as expected w/o any errors! Can you show table info Tab to see details of how table is set?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, added  the requested info

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add additional pseudo filter? But this may be more costly compared to UNION ALL because it could still read non necessary partitions:

```
select *
from table
where 
business_day >= "2018-12-01"
AND (business_day >= "2018-12-01" AND business_day <= "2019-01-01"
     OR business_day >= "2019-12-01" AND business_day <= "2010-01-01"
     OR business_day >= "2020-12-01" AND business_day <= "2021-01-01"
    )
```

Comment: I think that works, but is significantly more expensive. with union all, i'm repeating the sql query and that bothers me